# OAuth2 token request failing

Tags: rest-api, integration, rest

My access token request is failing with the following error response in HTTP Response.

{
error: "invalid_client_id"
error_description: "client identifier invalid"
}

I am trying with the Username-Password flow for OAuth.

I am testing with "Advanced REST Client" in Chrome.

[image]

[image]

This is my payload

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token&grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrDhLqebweqGDkIkyGQRjYkfWtLLSwKDal0AhSWZIG7EU7gsYQn4JjfCt.SOoBrJLmyEpslT&clientSecret=7217724494220744623&username=apiuser1982@gmail.com&password=qazwsx123UKBZb1SEA3LgCcptvGBb8ibpk
```

All my credentials are correct and I am stuck.

My connected app settings (Client Key/Secret) are also right without any typos and such.

Can someone help as to what could be wrong ?

Comment: As the error saying itself I'm confused what's that `grant_type` in your request.   It looks like some code

Comment: The error message is not from my payload.. It is given by the Rest client after processing my payload.

Comment: error message is fine, am asking the value for `grant_type` in your request. It looks like some generated code where it shouldn't be as I think

Comment: You are absolutely right !!!..Let me repush with the correct payload

Comment: grant type error no longer occurs as expected but i am getting this error now..I have updated the post with the latest behaviour. The hardcoded username/password is right and can you let me know as to where should i start looking now ?..thanks

Comment: If you are comfortable with all, try again it after sometimes. May be it's taking sometime to activate client id.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and what fixed it was choosing "Send client credentials in body" in the "Client Authentication" dropdown.

[image: PostMan built-in oAuth]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I see that there are one thing wrong with your request. There should be no space/enter in the client Id. I see that there is an enter in your request in Postman.

I tried the same request after removing the enter and got invalid client credentials instead of invalid client identifier. Possibly the one you have provided here have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you are making a POST request on Postman, to retrieve the SF access token, you must append the Security Token with the Password (i.e. yourpasswordxxxxx , where xxxxx is your security token).

The security key can be found in Salesforce by clicking on your name -> settings -> my personal information -> reset my security token -> On clicking Reset Security Token a new security token will be sent to your email.

Thus, the below payload should be your API URL (where XXXXXXXXXX is your security token).

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token&grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrDhLqebweqGDkIkyGQRjYkfWtLLSwKDal0AhSWZIG7EU7gsYQn4JjfCt.SOoBrJLmyEpslT&client_secret=7217724494220744623&username=apiuser1982@gmail.com&password=qazwsx123UKBZb1SEA3LgCcptvGBb8ibpkXXXXXXXXXX

**Note :** Before calling the above API you must first configure your SF Connected App, where you should Enable OAuth Settings and set https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback as your Callback URL.

Hope this helps, 
Thanks,

Parikhit

Answer (score 1):

After testing in postman i got a success response.

The only change i have made is given below

```
clientSecret -> client_secret
```

And the call should be a POST call.

If you need anything else you can comment bellow.